# Application logs in database or file

Tags: php, database, file, logging

I want to make a detailed logger for my application and because it can get very complex and have to save a lot of different things I wonder where is the best to save it in a database(and if database wich kind of database is better for this kind of opperations) or in file(and if file what kind of format:text,csv,json,xml).My first thought was of course file because in database I see a lot of problems but I also want to be able to show those logs  and for this is easier with database.

Answer (score 0):

I am building a log for HIPPA compliance and here is my rough implementation (not finished yet).

**File VS. DB**
I use a database table to store the last 3 months of data. Every night a cron will run and push the older data (data past 3 months) off into compressed files. I haven't written this script yet but it should not be difficult. That way the last 3 months can be searched, filtered, etc. But the database won't be overwhelmed with log entries.

**Database Preference**
I am using MSSQL because I don't have a choice. I usually prefer MySQL though as it has better pager optimization. If you are doing more than a very minimal amount of searching and filtering or if you are concerned about performance you may want to consider an apache solr middle man. I'm not a db expert so I can't give you much more than that.

**Table Structure**
My table is 5 columns. Date, Operation (create, update, delete), Object (patient, appointment, doctor), ObjectID, and Diff (a serialized array of before and after values, changed values only no empty or unchanged values for the sake of saving space).

**Summary**
The most important piece to consider is: Do you need people to be able to access and filter/search the data regularly? IF yes consider a database for the recent history or the most important data.
If no a file is probably a better option.

My hybrid solution is also worth considering. I'll be pushing the files off to a amz file server so it doesn't take up my web servers space.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the detail & Complex logger with using the some existing libraries like log4php because that is fully tested as part of the performance compare to you design custom for your self and it will also save time of development, I personally used few libraries from php and dotnet for our complex logger need in some financial and medical domain projects

here i would suggest if you need to do from the php then use this

https://logging.apache.org/log4php/

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer is actually: Neither.
Neither the file or a DB give you proper search, filtering, and you need that when looking at logs.  I deal with logs all day long (see http://sematext.com/logsene to see why), and I'd tackle this as follows:

1. log to file
2. use a lightweight log shipper (e.g. Logagent or Filebeat)
3. index logs into either your own Elasticsearch cluster (if you don't mind managing and learning) or one of the Cloud log management services (if you don't want to deal with Elasticsearch management, scaling, etc. -- Logsene, Loggly, Logentries...)